# php exec ограничить

Tags: php

функции php exec, shell_exec позволяют выйти за пределы домашней папки, хотя установлен open_basedir в конфиге apache. Как решить эту проблему? или же ограничить разрешить выполнять через них только пару команд? У пользователя установлен /bin/false, id показывает, что выполняется от пользователя у которого нет прав для доступа к шеллу. Как лучше решить задачу?

Comment: лучше вообще не использовать эти команды в коде. который выполняется апачем

Comment: Так не получается.

Comment: Тогда уж лучше написать скрипт и запускать его, а он уже будет "делать дела"